# Python27-try/except issue

Tags: gae-python27

Why the else function not running after below, it can be saved:

```
def OnButtonSavedata(default):
    Number=numberctrl.GetValue()
    if len(Number)==9:
        try:
            float(Number)
        except ValueError:
            wx.MessageBox('Just number please','Info',wx.OK|wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
    else:..
```

Please help me what I left off.

Thanks